# Delete a textbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textBoxCount = 0;
    $('body').append('<input type="button" id="add" value="add">');
    $('#add').click(function() {
        textBoxCount++;
        $('body').append('<br><input type="text" id="textBox-'+textBoxCount+'"><input type="button" class="deleteTextBox" id="deleteTextBox-'+textBoxCount+'" value="x">');
    });
    $('.deleteTextBox').click(function() {
        $(this).prev().remove();
    });
});
```

I don't get the TextBoxes deleted !

Comment: use delegated events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clicked element (`.deleteTextBox`) is not present on document ready, so `$('.deleteTextBox').click()` cannot detect it.

Try `on()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteTextBox', function() {
   $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

Comment: well, you are my hero ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/fL91rxd1/1/)

```
$('body').on('click', '.deleteTextBox', function() {        
    $(this).prev().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```